# Why does this Lorentz contraction acts on the $y$-axis?

Tags: special-relativity

Imagine we have a stick of length $l$ parallel to the $y$ axis, it's stationary for a system of reference $S$. Another system of reference $S^{'}$ moves in the $x$ direction with velocity $v$.
We send a beam of light from the origin to the end of the stick.

The beam reaches the end at $t_{1}=l/c$ in $S$.

Doing the Lorentz transform, $t_{1}^{'}=\gamma l/c$, so its length measured from $S^{'}$ is $\gamma l$, higher than in $S$ ($γ>1$).

Why does it expand in the $y$ axis, when the velocity is purely in the $x$ axis?

EDIT (DERIVATION OF $t^{'}_{1}$): As the Lorentz transformation states: $t_{1}^{'}= \gamma(t_{1}-x_{1}v/c^{2})$ but $x_{1}=0$ in the system of reference $S$, so we have $t_{1}^{'}=\gamma t_{1}$ , then $t^{'}_{1}=\gamma l/c$

Comment: Looks like an error to me, I don't know how you did the Loretnz transform but I don't see why $t1'=\gamma l/c$.

Comment: I've edited the question, so you have the derivation there, I simply applied the lorentz transformation formula for system of reference moving purely in the x axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the S' frame, the light travels diagonally, both along the x-axis due to the relative motion and vertically along the stick. The light has to travel farther to reach the end of the stick, so it takes longer due to always moving at the same speed regardless of the reference frame.

Comment: It makes sense, but how do we measure the lenght of the stick from S' to check it's the same then?

Comment: @MarcoVillalobos Since lengths don't change in the direction perpendicular to the direction of motion, you can use a normal meter stick to measure the length of the stick as it goes by. If you want to use the photon, you use the Pythagorean theorem. The time of flight in the S' frame gives the hypotenuse, the horizontal motion during that time gives one of the legs, and the stick height is the third leg.